# Does DbUnit support sequences in inserts using Hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, junit, dbunit

I have integrated **DbUnit** into my app which uses **Hibernate** and *Oracle SQL*; I created the datamodel as tables **only** however sequence creation **failed**:

```
create sequence CARS_LOGIN_SEQ
minvalue 1
maxvalue 999999999999999999999999999
start with 1
increment by 1;
```

I couldn't believe it; no problem, I skipped the sequences, and selects work, however when my app comes to insert a row in the test case, it fails!

Here's my use of the sequence in the hibernate XML file:

```
<id name="id" column="PARTY_ID">
    <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">cars_party_seq</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

What does this mean, if my code uses sequences, then I can't use DbUnit?

Note I'm using DbUnit 2.4.8, but could upgrade if needed.

Answer (score 0):

OK so it turns out sequences **are supported**, which makes sense.

However, the sequence creation SQL should be simply like this (if you don't want to start with 0):

> create sequence CARS_LOGIN_SEQ start with 5;